# Rendering PDF Page showing page guidelines and dates on edges of screen

Tags: ios

Im attempting to render the pages of a pdf document.  Opening the pdf in Adobe Reader shows the pages correctly.  When I attempt to render it into a view, I get additional 'items' on the edges of the screen.  They look like guide lines and page creation dates.  I've tried using all the PDFBox options but I have not been able to find the right options.  I'm using a TiledPDFView class to render the page. It uses `CATiledLayer` class.  Here are the relevant methods.

```
-(void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, self.bounds);
    CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0.0, self.bounds.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);
    //I've tried many options in the PDFBox parameter.
    CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(pdfPage, kCGPDFCropBox, self.bounds, 0, false));
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(ctx, pdfPage);
    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
}
```

I'm really unsure how to remove these guidelines.  It might just be an issue of my bounds.

[image: The Image!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by not using the `CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform` method and just doing the transforms myself.  I found a bit of code that I'll share here for future reference.  I do not remember where I got the code from though :(.

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
    CGContextGetCTM(context);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context,1,-1);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -rect.size.height);
    CGRect mediaRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(pdfPage, kCGPDFCropBox);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, rect.size.width/mediaRect.size.width, rect.size.height / mediaRect.size.height);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -mediaRect.origin.x, -mediaRect.origin.y);
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, pdfPage);
}
```